# Elementor Custom Control: How to get input value?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm creating a custom widget and control in Elementor. What I want to achieve is a button, when clicked, will open the file dialog to let the user choose a file. Once a file is chosen, an ajax script will upload the file and returns the download link. Please see below the pictures of what I want to achieve.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The file is uploading properly and I can set the value of the hidden input field with the file's url. But I can't get the url to show on the frontend.

Here is my current code:

Control (file-upload.php)

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

class File_Upload_Control extends \Elementor\Base_Data_Control {

    public function get_type() {
        return 'fileupload';
    }

    protected function get_default_settings() {
        return [
            'label' => 'Download File',
        ];
    }

    public function content_template() {

        $control_uid = $this->get_control_uid();
        ?>
        <div class="elementor-control-field">
            <label for="<?php echo $control_uid; ?>" class="elementor-control-title">{{{ data.label }}}</label>
            <div class="elementor-control-input-wrapper">
                <p class="eae-form-notice"></p>
                <form action="" method="post" name="eae-file-upload-form">
                    <?php wp_nonce_field('eae-file-upload'); ?>
                    <input type="file" name="eae-file">
                </form>
            </div>
            <input id="<?php echo $control_uid; ?>" type="hidden" name="eae-file-link" class="elementor-control-tag-area" title="{{ data.title }}" data-setting="{{ data.name }}" />
        </div>
        <?php

    }

    public function enqueue() {
        wp_register_script( 'eae-file-upload', plugins_url( 'assets/js/file-upload.js', __DIR__ ) );

        $data = array(
                    'upload_url' => admin_url('async-upload.php'),
                    'ajax_url'   => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
                    'nonce'      => wp_create_nonce('media-form')
                );

        wp_localize_script( 'eae-file-upload', 'su_config', $data );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'eae-file-upload' );
    }

}
```

Widget (download-button.php)

```
<?php
class Download_Button_Widget extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'Download Button';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return __( 'Download Button', 'elementor-artbees-extension' );
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'fa fa-download';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'basic' ];
    }

    protected function _register_controls() {
        $this->start_controls_section(
            'content_section',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Content', 'elementor-artbees-extension' ),
                'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'button_text',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Text', 'elementor-artbees-extension' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TEXT,
                'input_type' => 'text',
                'default' => __( 'Click here', 'elementor-artbees-extension' ),
                'placeholder' => __( 'Enter button text here', 'elementor-artbees-extension' ),
            ]
        );

        $this->add_control(
            'download_file',
            [
                // 'label' => __( 'Download File', 'elementor-artbees-extension' ),
                'type' => 'fileupload',
            ]
        );
    }

    protected function render() {
        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

        echo '<div class="eae-text">';

        echo $settings['button_text'] . '<br>';
        echo $settings['download_file'];

        echo '</div>';
    }

    protected function _content_template() {}

}
```

JS (file-upload.js)

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var notice = $('.eae-form-notice');
        var form = $('form[name=eae-file-upload-form]');
        var file = form.find('input[name=eae-file]');

        file.live('change', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('action', 'upload-attachment');
            formData.append('async-upload', e.target.files[0]);
            formData.append('name', e.target.files[0].name);
            formData.append('_wpnonce', su_config.nonce);

            $.ajax({
                url: su_config.upload_url,
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    file.hide();
                    notice.html('Uploading&hellip;');
                },
                success: function(resp) {
                    // console.log(resp.data.url);
                    $('input[name=eae-file-link]').val(resp.data.url);
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Try `var_dump( $settings );` to see the array items; the file URL should be somewhere. And have you tried `$settings = $this->get_settings();` ?

Comment: hi @SallyCJ, I tried `$settings = $this->get_settings();` but didn't work. I changed the input hidden to input text just to see if it works. Then on the input text I tried typing and it's automatically changing the text live on the frontend. But when I use the upload function, the javascript changes the value of the input but it doesn't automatically change on the frontend.

Comment: @SallyCJ to help you better understand my problem, here's a short video I recorded. http://somup.com/cqjVe7eoFX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not about getting the value — `$settings['download_file']` (in PHP) would give you that value, if any.

What you're really looking for, is to make Elementor aware of the file input changes, so that the new value will be saved by Elementor.

And the trick is, trigger the `input` event on the file input after the file has been successfully uploaded:

1. In `file-upload.js`, find this:

   ```js
   $('input[name=eae-file-link]').val(resp.data.url);
   ```
2. And change it to:

   ```js
   $('input[name=eae-file-link]').val(resp.data.url).trigger('input');
   ```

[Reference.](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/3008#issuecomment-353968304)

Comment: It worked! Thanks!